# How use "adb" command line to check Android device FW version?

Tags: android, adb

We want to use adb command to check Android device FW version. But we don't know, how to use adb command line to get Android device FW version. How use "adb" command line to check Android device FW version?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Android version with the following command

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
```

otherwise, you can get the API lever with this other command

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
```

Run the following command to get a list of all the possible properties

```
adb shell getprop
```